# Chrome Extension Multi URL filtering

Tags: regex, url, google-chrome-extension

I am having trouble making my chrome extension work with multiple URL's What should be the format for listing URL's to match?

```
chrome.webNavigation.onDOMContentLoaded.addListener(function (o) {
chrome.tabs.executeScript(o.id, { 
    code: "////////" 
})}, {
    url: [
      { urlContains: ['/shop/jacket', 'shop/t-shirt']}
    ]
});
```

I'm assuming a regex would work, but how would I write that?

Comment: Why are you doing this the roundabout way with programmatic injection? What makes the manifest-declared content scripts unfit for you?

Comment: To be honest, this is my first extension. I followed some research and it led me to doing it this way.

Comment: My point being, for performance reasons it may be best to declare scripts in `content_scripts` field in the manifest if all you need is to match substrings of the path.

Comment: Ok, so how would I add listeners to say DOMcontentLoaded event in a content script?

Comment: You could just add a listener to the `document` element; but content scripts are by default injected with [`"run_at" : "document_idle"`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#run_at), so they are guaranteed to run _after_ (static) DOM content is loaded and parsed. So you need to do exactly nothing. Note that no method can magically understand when _dynamic_ content is loaded in all cases.

Comment: Great, thanks for your help. I will take a look at it. Also, with dynamic content I have had some success using setTimeout and waiting for a desired element to not =null. Probably not something I should be doing, but it works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because `urlContains` expects a single string only.

The simplest regex operator that matches "`A` or `B`" is `A|B`.

So, in your case `{ urlMatches : "/shop/jacket|shop/t-shirt" }`. It's simple in your case since your URL  substrings do not contain special characters; in the general case you may need to `\`-escape some characters.